# Element API + checkboxes

Tags: plugin-elementapi

Using the Element API, I want to return the values from checkboxes (the $block->product field). These checkboxes are within a matrix that I am already gathering data from. Currently am doing this:

```
return [
'endpoints' => [
    'fullmembers.json' => [
        'elementType' => 'User',
        'criteria' => ['group' => 'fullMembership'],
        'transformer' => function(UserModel $member) {
            $businessCategories = [];
            foreach ($member->businessTypeMarketSectorsProducts as $block) {
                switch ($block->type->handle) {
                    case 'businessCategory':

                        $businessCategories[] = [
                            'businessType' => $block->businessType->value,
                            'marketSector' => $block->marketSector->value,
                            'product' => $block->product //Here you can see I'm calling the product field... 
                        ];
                        break;
                }
            }

            return [
                'id' => $member->id,
                'companyName' => $member->membersCompanyName,
                'addressLine3' => $member->membersAddressLine3,
                'lat' => $member->memberAddress->lat,
                'lng' => $member->memberAddress->lng,
                'email' => $member->email,
                // 'profile' => '/directory/company/' . $member->id . '/' . $member->username,
                'profile' => UrlHelper::getUrl("directory/company/{$member->id}"),
                'businessCategories' => $businessCategories
            ];
        },
    ]
]
];
```

Here is a sample response:

```
    {
  "id": "1506",
  "companyName": "Airsprung Group Plc",
  "addressLine3": "",
  "lat": "51.33188454",
  "lng": "-2.20657303",
  "email": "email@email.co.uk",
  "profile": "http:\/\/craft.fira\/directory\/company\/1506",
  "businessCategories": [{
    "businessType": "Manufacture",
    "marketSector": "Domestic",
    "product": {
      "0": {
        "label": "Beds",
        "value": "Beds",
        "selected": true
      },
      "1": {
        "label": "Mattresses",
        "value": "Mattresses",
        "selected": true
      },
      "2": {
        "label": "Seating \/ upholstery",
        "value": "Seating \/ upholstery",
        "selected": true
      }
    }
  }, {
    "businessType": "Manufacture",
    "marketSector": "Contract",
    "product": {
      "0": {
        "label": "Beds",
        "value": "Beds",
        "selected": true
      },
      "1": {
        "label": "Mattresses",
        "value": "Mattresses",
        "selected": true
      },
      "2": {
        "label": "Seating \/ upholstery",
        "value": "Seating \/ upholstery",
        "selected": true
      }
    }
  }]
}
```

I would like the response to just show the values of the product checkboxes. Can you suggest a way to do this so that I am not returning the label and selected states? Ideally something like this:

```
"product": {"Beds", "Mattresses", "Seating \/ upholstery"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to foreach the $block->product to include the selected values (or labels)

```
return [
    'endpoints' => [
        'fullmembers.json' => [
            'elementType' => 'User',
            'criteria' => ['group' => 'fullMembership'],
            'transformer' => function(UserModel $member) {
                $businessCategories = [];
                foreach ($member->businessTypeMarketSectorsProducts as $block) {
                    switch ($block->type->handle) {
                        case 'businessCategory':
                            $productValues = [];
                            foreach ($block->product as $product) {
                                if ($product->selected) {
                                    $productValues[] = $product->value;
                                }
                            }
                            $businessCategories[] = [
                                'businessType' => $block->businessType->value,
                                'marketSector' => $block->marketSector->value,
                                'product' => $productValues
                            ];
                            break;
                    }
                }

                return [
                    'id' => $member->id,
                    'companyName' => $member->membersCompanyName,
                    'addressLine3' => $member->membersAddressLine3,
                    'lat' => $member->memberAddress->lat,
                    'lng' => $member->memberAddress->lng,
                    'email' => $member->email,
                    // 'profile' => '/directory/company/' . $member->id . '/' . $member->username,
                    'profile' => UrlHelper::getUrl("directory/company/{$member->id}"),
                    'businessCategories' => $businessCategories
                ];
            },
        ]
    ]
];
```

Comment: Thanks chris. You've nailed it! The output is now: {"businessType":"Manufacture","marketSector":"Contract","product":["Beds","Mattresses","Seating \/ upholstery"]}]},